# Not getting example to fit Yoneda

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

So apparently I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.
I've read a proof of the Yoneda lemma and understand it from Riehl's book, but to try it out, I tried an example.

My input category:
C has objects X and Y only, with just the arrows,
$id_X : X →X$
$g : X →X$
$f : X→Y$
And of course $Y$'s $id$ arrow.
I choose $g^2=id_X$, and with only $f:X→Y$, $f$ composed with $g$ must be $f$.

I pick a functor $A:C→Set$, such that
$AX =$ {0,1}, and $Ag = id_{AX}$, and as far as I can tell everything up to now is legal.

With $g$ defined the way it is, then
$g^{*}: C(X,X) → C(X,X)$ has,
$g^{*}(g) = g^2 = id_X$
$g^{*}(id_X) = g$,
So $g^*$ swaps the elements of $C(X,X)$.
But as I've defined $AX$ and $Ag$, I can't see a natural transformation
$α:C(-, X) →A$ that seems to commute the square for $g$, when according to Yoneda there should exist two natural transformations BC $AX$ has two elements!

Further, when I formed the natural square for $f:X→Y$, I get four functions mapping $C(X,X) →AX$ and the $Y$ component $α_Y$ can be whatever that fits, so I figured doing squares for $id_X$ and $g$ would restrict to two for $α_X$, which is when I found the first issue I mentioned.

Can someone please spell this out, I feel like it really shouldn't be this complicated... 
Edit:
Fixed it from 'there is no" to "I can see".

Comment: If you want to pick a functor you will need to specify $AY$ and $A(f):AX\to AY$... Or maybe $A(f) : AY\to AX$ if you meant to pick a contravariant functor (i.e. a functor $C^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riehl (like other sources) state Yoneda using $C(X, -)$ rather than $C(-,X)$ (of course, there's a dual version with $C(-, X)$ - see Exercise 2.2.i) - I'm not sure if this is a typo or if you really want the dual version.  Assuming it's a typo:

What I think you're concerned about is the following diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
C(X,X) & \stackrel{\alpha_X}\to & A(X)\\
\downarrow C(X,g) & & \downarrow A(g)=\operatorname{id} \\
C(X,X) & \stackrel{\alpha_X} \to & A(X)
\end{array}
$$
Is that right? You say there aren't any natural transformations $\alpha$ making it commute, but there are two. One $\alpha_X$ sends both $\operatorname{id}_X$ and $g$ to 0, the other sends them both to 1. This is what Yoneda says should happen - the natural transformations are in bijection with $A(X)=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Yeah wow, I knew it had to be something small but crazy how I overlooked that. I was aware of 2-1 functions, but just had a (long lol) moment of tunnel vision looking at the id functions I kept "seeing" alpha_X as a 1-1!

Comment: Which helps answer the other issue I originally had (but mentioned toward the end of my overall question above): even though there are four total functions from C(X,X) to AX, only two are admissible, which i suspected would happen. Thanks!